# How to display result of PHP render in HTML ID

Tags: php, html, wordpress

After digging internet for an answer I cannot find any idea about how to deal with my issue. I think the problem is common for someone who knows PHP a little bit.

To describe the situation. For some custom WordPress plugin I've got two PHP files: **ff_config.php** and **loantest_form.php**. First file contains some configurations of plugin plus following lines:

```
/**--------------------------TABLE SHORTCODES-----------------------*/
function render_loantest_form() {
include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'front/loantest_form.php');
}
add_shortcode( 'render_loantest_form' , render_loantest_form );

/**--------------------------DISPLAY PLUGIN IN FOOTER-----------------------*/
add_action('wp_footer', 'display_loantest');
function display_loantest() {
echo render_loantest_form();
}
```

Which I suppose rendering second file containing enqueue scripts (js/css) and whole HTML output and placing in `wp_footer` where it exactly is on my page.

**The question is:** how to change mentioned lines to allow me to place render result (loantest_form.php) in specific div / id on page (for example `#sidebar-slider`)?

Comment: you can do this using jquery

Comment: That code there creates a shortcode - which you can use in any part of the WP pages (in posts, in sidebar-widgets, etc.) - just use the shortcode? And remove the add_action if you don't want it in the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display your shortcode in a template file,

```
echo do_shortcode('[render_loantest_form]');
```

Enable the use of shortcodes in text widgets.

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

And inside the text editor

```
[render_loantest_form]
```

You can read more about [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

Note that you need to be sure that the file load in the render function is good and that it returns the expect content.

Comment: Hey Benoti, many thanks for helpful advise, rendered view started to work where I wanted to have it just placing the shortcode there :)